# JS variable in jquery(ajax) appending html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

**EDIT (done)**: I figure it out. Syntax is `<button onclick="editItem('+data[i].id+')">EDIT</button>'`

I have this, it generates all the objects in database, showing `id`, `name` and `actions` - both buttons have different `onclick function` where i want to send `object id` for future things.

I just need an answer how to put `data[i].id` in `'<button onclick="editItem(ID)">EDIT</button>'`, which syntax?

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type:'GET',
        url:'api',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

                var row = $(

                    '<tr>' +

                    '<td>' +
                        data[i].id +
                    '</td>' +

                    '<td>' +
                        data[i].name +
                    '</td>' +

                    '<td>' +
                    '   <button onclick="editItem(ID)">EDIT</button>' +
                    '   <button onclick="deleteItem(ID)">DELETE</button>' +
                    '</td>' +

                    '</tr>'

                );
                $('#my_table').append(row);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: try to use template literals?
`<button onclick="editItem(${data[i].id})">EDIT</button>`

Comment: @danu not working

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to add the ID to the buttons as [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and use a [delegated event handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to handle the clicks

```js
// Set up event handlers on your table to listen for button clicks
const table = $("#my_table")
  .on("click", "button[data-edit]", function(e) { // EDIT button
    const id = this.dataset.edit

    // and so on, eg...
    editItem(id)
  })
  .on("click", "button[data-delete]", function(e) { // DELETE button
    const id = this.dataset.delete

    // and so on, eg... 
    deleteItem(id)
  })
  
// Using jQuery's DOM helpers makes for more concise code IMO
$.getJSON("api")
  .done(data => table.append(data.map(({ id, name }) =>
    $("<tr>").append([
      $("<td>", { text: id }),
      $("<td>", { text: name }),
      $("<td>").append([
        $("<button>", { text: "EDIT", "data-edit": id }),
        $("<button>", { text: "DELETE", "data-delete": id })
      ])
    ])
  )))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, still.. i don't have much experience to implent this.

Comment: @sam00vun0c sorry, I don't understand your question